# Database schema for Sales Commissions

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a database with table titles which contains different titles, code(short code for the name) and commission of that title on other titles for instance.
I have a table named Title

```
Id           Name             Code        CommissionOnA   CommissionOnEng
1            Admin             A            0                15
2            Engineer          Eng          1                0
```

Now Is it good to have table schema like this, as the titles will change and can be inserted, updated or deleted dynamically. So with my current approach I have to alter table and add another column to it, in order to add commission for new title.

Is there any better way to do it, considering in mind that this also support multilevel sale heirarchy. Schema for any database is fine, but for MySql is preferred.

The Scenerio is, that the form where user creates a new title, dynamically renders all the titles that exist in the table with the textbox, so that  when user creates a new title, he should be able to add commissions corresponding to other titles for the new title.

for instance if user creates a new Title name "Consultant" with code "c", he should see textboxes for Admin, Engineer, so that when user saves it, a row in the table gets created which has following data

```
Id     Name        Code        CommissionOnA   CommissionOnEng  CommissionOnC
1      Admin        A            0                15             0
2      Engineer     Eng          1                0              0
3      Consultant   C            12               5              0
```

Now I have another table called Employees

```
Id  Name  Title  ManagerId
1   Rob   1       Null
2   Kate  2       1
3   Eli   3       2
4   Al    2       3
```

Now when Ido recursion, each time a junior get sale, a commission should be transfered to his manager as well as manager of his manager based on the commission specified in the title table.

So, when Al sells something, than Eli should get commission of 5 as, title of Eli is Consultant and Eli is boss of Al, so Employee with title Consultant(3) get commission of 5, if Employee with title Engineer(2) sells something.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are actually using.  Feel free to add *one* database tag.

Comment: Why can't you simply have one `Commission` column? If a title can only ever have one level of commission, you shouldn't need multiple columns.

Comment: Can you better describe the business problem? Is that table a list of job titles / employment positions? What is "A" and "Eng"? I'm confused by those two values appearing as values in a column as well as names of columns (which suggests maybe this table design is not yet normalized). What is the business scenario? Is it that any person working with this job title has a certain commission rate?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to normalise your table schemas so you don't need to add new columns instead put those related columns into their own table and then join these records via a foreign key.

For example, create a new table named commissions, then have a column for its unique ID, the ID that relates to the titles table and the commission amount:

```
commissions
----------------------------
id (INT, NOT NULL, Primary Key)
titles_id (INT, NOT NULL)
amount (INT, NOT NULL, DEFAULT=0)
```

and the data would look like:

```
id titles_id amount
1  1         15
2  2         1
```